# Export computer info to CSV file using get-content

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am hoping to get some assistance getting what I'd call an easy script working but I've hit my PS knowledge ceiling. I've found some posts where others tried to do something similar but it hasn't helped me.

I've got the concept working where it outputs the data into a CSV file for each computer, but the information for each computer is the same. I've modified the script a number of times but I am out of ideas now. I am running PS 5.0. Here is what I have so far:

```
$Computers = get-content "C:\Users\test\documents\computers.txt"
$ExportLocation = "C:\Users\test\documents"

$Score = Get-CimInstance Win32_ReliabilityStabilityMetrics | measure SystemStabilityIndex -Average | select-object -ExpandProperty Average
$Manufacturer = Get-ComputerInfo | select -ExpandProperty "CsManufacturer"
$Output = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    ComputerName = $Computer
    StabilityScore = $Score
    Manufacturer = $Manufacturer

  } | Select-Object ComputerName,StabilityScore,Manufacturer
}
$Output | Export-CSV $ExportLocation\StabilityResults.csv -Append -Force -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would like to collect the information from the remote computers, right?
Currently you are collecting Score and Manufacturer from the local computer and put a different computer name in front.

I would do it like this, and will explain why:

```
$Computers = get-content "C:\Users\test\documents\computers.txt"
$ExportLocation = "C:\Users\test\documents"

$Output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Score = (Get-CimInstance Win32_ReliabilityStabilityMetrics | measure SystemStabilityIndex -Average).Average
        Manufacturer = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Manufacturer
    }
} | Select-Object ComputerName,Score,Manufacturer

$Output | Export-CSV $ExportLocation\StabilityResults.csv -Append -Force -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation
```

I would use Invoke-command to access the remote computers, as it sends the command against 32 computers in parallel (by default). The number of computers could be increased or decreased using the variable Throttlelimit.

If you are doing it with a loop like foreach, you would be running it sequentially, which obviously would be slower.

I have replaced `Get-ComputerInfo` with `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Manufacturer` as you will get the same result, but faster. `Get-ComputerInfo` collects too much info, therefore is slower.

The variable `$env:computername` returns the computer name from the remote machine.

Give it a run and provide a feedback. I hope the explanations were clear and useful!

Comment: Hey Ivan, amazing!! Thanks so much! That did the trick.

I just had to update the select-object after the invoke-command to say "ComputerName,Score,Manufacturer" to match the PSCustomerObject property for anyone who wants to run this.

I've also added the ThrottleLimit command to it as I'll eventually run this on more than 32 nodes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have edited the answer! Glad to be of service! :)